# Open original Microsoft Office document (not "version 1") on Mac OS X Lion restart

Tags: osx-lion, microsoft-office

My MacBook Pro running Lion has been frequently freezing lately, and I've had to restart with the power button. When Lion starts up again, the Microsoft Office applications that were running start and load different autosaved versions of the documents I had open (i.e. it does not open abc.xlsx but [version 1] of abc.xlsx). Sometimes it also opens the original files. Several times I've inputted data into these "version 1" files, only to try to save it and realize that it isn't the original file and is sometimes missing data that is contained in the original file. Is there any way to make autorecover open the actual document with the unsaved changes, instead of making a new temporary version?

Answer (score 0):

Autosave saves the unsaved version of a document so you don't loose unsaved changes in it. If you have saved the important changes and want to discard the changes since your last save, ignore/cancel the auto-recovery completely and reopen the original file from disk.